# right-continuous extension of nondecreasing right-continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble with showing that the construction in my solution to the following problem is well defined:

> Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}$ be dense. Let $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be a non-decreasing right-continuous function. Show that there is a unique right-continuous, non-decreasing extension $\hat{f}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

*Attempt*: I defined $\hat{f}(x)=\lim_{y\to x+,y\in D}f(y)$. Non-decreasing is trivial and right-continuity is clear by $\mathbb{R}$ being complete. Let $g$ be another extension, then: $g(x)=\lim_{y\to x+,y\in D}f(y)=f(x)$ so this extension is unique. But I'm not able to show that my $\hat{f}$ is independent of the choice of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If given another dense sequence *y*, take the union of that and the original sequence *x* to get another dense sequence *z*.

If this new sequence *z* doesn't also converge to the same function as *x*, then contradiction.

And if the second dense sequence *y*, which is a subsequence of the convergent new dense sequence *z*, doesn't converge to the same limit as *z*, also contradiction.